# JS Operator with String

Tags: javascript

Hii All,

```
"Aardvark" < "Zoroaster"  # return "true"
```

I think, this is very basic.
But I can't understand above statement which is collected one of the js article.

Shall u explained them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare strings using the equality, greater-than and less-than operators.

Using either greater-than or less-than will perform a dictionary style comparison, ie *which comes first in the dictionary?*

Comment: Phil, "dictionary style comparison" means, each character assign ascii ?
Shall u explain "dictionary style comparison"

Comment: But dictionaries are usually sorted without regard for case, noting that of course the vast majority of words in the dictionary are all lowercase - are you saying that the JS greater-than and less-than operators are also case *insensitive* when used on strings?

Comment: @nnnnnn It looks like uppercase is considered lower than lowercase, ie `"a" > "A"`

Comment: Yeah, I believe the comparison is based on the Unicode character order.

Answer (score 1):

This basically means that in JS "Aardvark" is considered lesser than "Zoroaster" because JS uses something called [Lexicographical Ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), also known as Dictionary Order because dictionaries also use the same order when listing words.

Comment: The JS greater-than and less-than operators do not sort in dictionary order unless you convert both strings to lowercase (or both to upper) before hand. If you have mixed case then "abc" < "bcd" but "abc" > "Bcd".